# If Then Else Statements

Tags: python

I am trying to translate the below statement into Python but struggle with a reoccuring error.

```
hours = input (prompt1)
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

*A worker gets paid an hourly wage, when working up to 40 hours per week. When the time at work goes above 40 hours in a week, the worker is being paid overtime rate, which is 1.5 times the hourly wage. Given the hours worked per week, and the hourly wage, compute the weekly salary of the worker.*

```
prompt1 = 'How many hours did you work?\n'

try:
hours = input (prompt1)

prompt2 = 'What is your hourly rate?\n'

rate = input (prompt2)

hours = float(hours)

rate = float(rate)

print float(hours) * float(rate*1.5)

except:
print('Error, Please enter a number')
```

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: if you didn't know Pyhton works on indentation.

Comment: @RandomGuy Your edit completely destroys the OP's problem. Their problem is they don't know how Python is indented, if it's indented like this then it's most likely valid code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python there are no `{}` or `begin` +`end` it works using identation. You code should look like:

```
prompt1 = 'How many hours did you work?\n'

try:
   hours = input (prompt1)
   prompt2 = 'What is your hourly rate?\n'
   rate = input (prompt2)
   hours = float(hours)
   rate = float(rate)
   if(hours > 40):
      rate = rate * 1.5
   print float(hours) * float(rate*1.5)

except:
   print('Error, Please enter a number')
```

Comment: Great. That works. Do you know how I can integrate "if someone enters >40 hours, then rate*1.5 else 1.0"?

Comment: @User2017 That's another question. | Please read [ask] and [help] and [mcve] and [SO question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to know what we expect and other guidelines on [so].

Comment: It's truth that is another question, but there you go. Check the code and please accept the answer

Comment: Brilliant. THANK YOU!

Comment: @User2017 the best way to say thanks in this website is giving the "green check". So anyone will know that my answer is the good one and I will get the recognizement of it. Just click in the check that is below the up/down arrows neear my answer.

Happy to help! :)